# Jenkins Continues Integration setup for Scala Maven project

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have started working on developing a Spark-Scala Maven project.We are a team of 6 developers commit code to git repository. We use Intellij IDE and codehup repository using GIT . Need to setup Jenkins for Continues integration testing and build. Could you please some one help me an approach to setup Jenkins or Spark-Scala project, Specifically needs a scala- jenkins in POM.XML? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question to include the steps you have taken so far and errors you are seeing, if you are not there yet try a google of "jenkins and scala".

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I did an initial analysis on Jenkin setup. I have a clear idea on how to setup a jenkin CI for a java project. and the same process i was trying to implement for scala project. As i have posted in my initial question i was specifically looking for pom.xml dependancies for a scala project.I tried over the internet search but couldn't find good information specifically about the required dependency for pom.xml. Also i know many people are building using SBT in my case am using scala with Maven. We did a good amount of research over past week.

Comment: users on SO will be much more likely to help if you share your research so we can give feedback! What does your Pom look like currently? How is it failing to build? What are the errors?

Answer (score -1):

Actually this is not a really answer, but I'd like you do the following steps:

1. Copy your question's title
2. Search it in [google](https://www.google.com.ph/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=A_xBWdagIovD8Aeil7HYDA#q=Jenkins+Continues+Integration+setup+for+Scala+Maven+project)
3. You will get a lots of results for this topic, and somethings will be interested your like

   - [Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment with Scala](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjhv-y-8b7UAhXHwLwKHT79AM4QFghEMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcircleci.com%2Fdocs%2F1.0%2Flanguage-scala%2F&usg=AFQjCNHdlJBLUgoU9ovPwRevGHMZ5ug_Ag)

Then for any problem you encountered, than ask the dedicated detailed questions.

That's it, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Liping, I tried google in first place but couldn't find good information specifically about the required dependency for pom.xml. Also i know many people are building using SBT in my case am using scala with Maven. We did a good amount of research over past week and finally posted a question here in stakeoverflow as a good place as if someone might tries scala+Maven+jenkins. I will continue to search over the internet but meantime if you have information please share. Thanks!

Comment: @SriBaru So can you update your question to add more detail info - what your tried, what's the problem, so this basic info can let you get your answer quickly.